# Match string with space by regular expression

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to make this regex `^(?!\-\-\sRoaming)` to match with `-- Roaming` but it doesnt. Am I matching correctly the white space between `--` and `Roaming` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which *won't* match if `-- Roaming` is anywhere in the input:

```
^(?!.*--\sRoaming)
```

Note that you don't need to escape the hyphens.

Comment: Sorry, it has to match to everything but not if `-- Roaming` is present, that is why it had `!`. But your regex is working for matching, how do I convert it to not to match if `-- Roaming` is present but do match if anything else is?

Answer (score 1):

The space is correct. But why wouldnt `--\sRoaming` work for you?

Comment: Because I can expect more words after `-- Roaming`, for example: `-- Roaming is present` but I need only to match if `-- Roaming` pattern is present.

Comment: It has to go through a firewall rule for a particular brand that matches only by regularexp on what we need.

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt work for `-- Roaming is present` (for example), because `-- Roaming` will always have something behind

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correctly matching that portion of the Regex.  I am a little hazy on Regex but what does the ?! mean?  I tried the \-\-\sRoaming part in http://regexpal.com/ and it was working correctly.

Comment: I can expect more words after `-- Roaming`, for example: `-- Roaming is present` but I need only to match if `-- Roaming` pattern is present.

Comment: You can put a $ at the end to stop this from happening.  $ is end of line identifier.  This may be the opposite of what you want.  Do you want to match when there are extra words or not?

Comment: `\-\-\sRoaming$` is NOT matching with `-- Roaming blah` and it should. Thank you for your time by the way.

Comment: Yeah okay, that's what I thought.  the $ would definitely not match "-- Roaming blah" since $ means that the end of line must be next.  What is the ?! for? \-\-\sRoaming definitely matches -- Roaming, so by process of elimination it seems like this would be the issue...  Also, the ^ at the beginning means that it must be at the beginning of a line.  Do you want this behavior?

Comment: Yes `-- Roaming` is always at the beggining of the line, but its not the only word, it might has some stuff behind.